# Cursor is null when i send query with content resolver

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

```
private static final int USER_ID=1;
private static final int DT=2;
private static final int VALUES_ALL=3;
private static final UriMatcher sUriMacher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);

static {
    sUriMacher.addURI("gr.hua.android.contentproviderapp","COORDINATES",VALUES_ALL);
    sUriMacher.addURI("gr.hua.android.contentproviderapp","COORDINATES/#",USER_ID);
    sUriMacher.addURI("gr.hua.android.contentproviderapp","COORDINATES/#",DT);
}

public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = new DBHelper(getContext()).getReadableDatabase();
        switch (sUriMacher.match(uri)){
            case USER_ID:
                String[] selargs =new String[1];  
                selargs[0]=uri.getLastPathSegment();  //the user_Id that i got
                String user=DBHelper.USER_ID;

            String[] coll =new String[1]; //the columns that I want to select
            coll[0]=DBHelper.KEY_LATITUDE;
            coll[1]=DBHelper.KEY_LONGITUDE; 

            return db.query(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME,coll,user+"=?",selargs,null,null,null);
        case DT:
            String[] selargs2 =new String[1];
            selargs2[0]=uri.getLastPathSegment();
            String[] coll2 =new String[1];
            coll2[0]=DBHelper.KEY_LATITUDE;
            coll2[1]=DBHelper.KEY_LONGITUDE;
            return db.query(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME,coll2,"_DT=?",selargs2,null,null,null); //the same as the user_id but we get the dt here
        case VALUES_ALL:
            return db.query(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME,null,null,null,null,null,null);
        default:
    }
    return null;
}
```

there is my content provider and i do the insert method  here to

```
Uri result =Uri.withAppendedPath(url,get3);

Cursor cursor =resolver.query(result,null,null,null,null);

 if (cursor!=null && cursor.getCount()>0){  //i got null here 
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder =new StringBuilder("");
                    while (cursor.moveToNext()) 
                     stringBuilder.append(cursor.getString(0) + " " + cursor.getString(1) + "");
                    }

                    get.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
                }else{
                    get.setText("This user not found");
```

the code above is the content resolver that i want to get from edittext(get3) the user_id that is a String type and put it in url path as LastPathSegment but the cursor rerturn null always 
if i send the url that do the sellect all work 
I search online i make some change but nothing i got Cursor=null when i debugg

Comment: you are adding the same `String path` with `addURI` method

Comment: i just remove the second addURI and the case but still get that cursor:null

Comment: so what `result` are you passing to `query()` method?

Comment: Uri result =Uri.withAppendedPath(url,get3);                                                  url is content://<package name of provider>/table name                           
and get 3 is edit text that user  gave to search the user id that is String

Comment: why dont you simply call `Log.d(TAG, "result: " + result)` and paste the output?

Comment: at my table i have information for user so the user search for name and i print out the information for that user

Comment: so what do you see on the logcat when you call `Log.d(TAG, "result: " + result);`?

Comment: show me this  content://<package name of provider>/table/get3 value sting

Comment: so it does not match any uri added to `sUriMacher`

Comment: i just found my mistakes i have to change on my UriMacher the #  with * cause i put string and at coll and coll2 i put 2 values string and i set it as String[1].. i have to set it as String[2]...Thanks for help!